# How to add/sum dynamic pivot columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm just after of adding/summarizing the dynamic pivot columns I've generated. is this possible?

ie.

Col1, Col2 , Col3 , Total

where Col1, Col2 and Col3 are dynamic pivot columns and Total is (Col1 + Col2 + Col3)

http://rextester.com/live/FFJV73881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (select SUM(SALES) FROM #REVENUE) as Total FROM
(SELECT ...
```